# Android Lollipop alertdialog xml

Tags: xml, android-layout-inflater

Всех с праздником. В моём приложении все окна зависят от системной разметки, что не очень радует. Хочется, чтобы на всех версиях андроида окошки выглядили одинаково. А именно - как в пятом андроиде. 
1) Где достать xml разметку этого окошка? 
2) Какой минимальный API поддерживает LayoutInflater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В моём приложении все окна зависят от системной разметки, что не очень
>   радует.

Это не только в Вашем приложении :)

1) Чтобы диалоги на всех версиях выглядели одинаково, необходимо использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Например эту: [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

или вот эту: [Material Dialog v1.3.1](https://github.com/drakeet/MaterialDialog)

При использовании диалогов из этих библиотек, диалоги на всех версиях Android будут как на скринах в описании библиотек.

2) LayoutInflater был добавлен в API Level 1
(смотри офф документацию [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html))

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужны сами XML то они лежат тут:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_material.xml

А вообще используйте AndroidSupportLibrary. 
Класс `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` выглядит везде одинаково (насколько это вообще возможно).